# Java image conversion to RGB565

Tags: java, image, rgb

I try to convert image to RGB565 format.
I read this image:

```
BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read(imagePathFile);
sendImg = new BufferedImage(CONTROLLER_LCD_WIDTH/*320*/, CONTROLLER_LCD_HEIGHT/*240*/, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);
sendImg.getGraphics().drawImage(bufImg, 0, 0, CONTROLLER_LCD_WIDTH/*320*/, CONTROLLER_LCD_HEIGHT/*240*/, null);
```

Here is it:

[image: picture before convertation]

Then I convert it to RGB565:

```
int numByte=0;
byte[] OutputImageArray = new byte[CONTROLLER_LCD_WIDTH*CONTROLLER_LCD_HEIGHT*2];

int i=0;
int j=0;
int len = OutputImageArray.length;

for (i=0;i<CONTROLLER_LCD_WIDTH;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<CONTROLLER_LCD_HEIGHT;j++) {

        Color c = new Color(sendImg.getRGB(i, j));
        int aRGBpix = sendImg.getRGB(i, j);
        int alpha;
        int red = c.getRed();
        int green = c.getGreen();
        int blue = c.getBlue();

        //RGB888
        red = (aRGBpix >> 16) & 0x0FF;
        green = (aRGBpix >> 8) & 0x0FF;
        blue = (aRGBpix >> 0) & 0x0FF; 
        alpha = (aRGBpix >> 24) & 0x0FF;

        //RGB565
        red = red >> 3;
        green = green >> 2;
        blue = blue >> 3;

        //A pixel is represented by a 4-byte (32 bit) integer, like so:
        //00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
        //^ Alpha  ^Red     ^Green   ^Blue
        //Converting to RGB565

        short pixel_to_send = 0;
        int pixel_to_send_int = 0;
        pixel_to_send_int = (red << 11) | (green << 5) | (blue);
        pixel_to_send = (short) pixel_to_send_int;


        //dividing into bytes
        byte byteH=(byte)((pixel_to_send >> 8) & 0x0FF);
        byte byteL=(byte)(pixel_to_send & 0x0FF);

        //Writing it to array - High-byte is second
        OutputImageArray[numByte]=byteH;
        OutputImageArray[numByte+1]=byteL;

        numByte+=2;
    }
}
```

Then I try to restore this from resulting array `OutputImageArray`:

```
i=0;
j=0;                        
numByte=0;
BufferedImage NewImg = new BufferedImage(CONTROLLER_LCD_WIDTH, CONTROLLER_LCD_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);
for (i=0;i<CONTROLLER_LCD_WIDTH;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<CONTROLLER_LCD_HEIGHT;j++) {

        int curPixel=0;
        int alpha=0x0FF;
        int red;
        int green;
        int blue; 

        byte byteL=0;
        byte byteH=0;

        byteH = OutputImageArray[numByte];
        byteL = OutputImageArray[numByte+1];

        curPixel= (byteH << 8) | (byteL);

        //RGB565
        red = (curPixel >> (6+5)) & 0x01F;
        green = (curPixel >> 5) & 0x03F;
        blue = (curPixel) & 0x01F;

        //RGB888
        red = red << 3;
        green = green << 2;
        blue = blue << 3;                                

        //aRGB
        curPixel = 0;
        curPixel = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue);

        NewImg.setRGB(i, j, curPixel);
        numByte+=2;

    }
}
```

I output this restored image. But I see that it looks very poor.

[image]

I expected the lost of pictures quality. 
But as I thought, this picture has to have almost the same quality as the previous picture. Is it right?
Is my code right?

Comment: I don't need alpha channel. I want to get RGB565 picture and send it like a sequence of (unsigned short) words. Microcontroller receives this picture and shows on LCD. I want to see on LCD almost the same Image like on PC. I don't understand anything. I converted image according to all the rules...

Comment: BufferedImage NewImg = new BufferedImage(CONTROLLER_LCD_WIDTH, CONTROLLER_LCD_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);  I changed it to BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB. But nothing has changed... May be I should use another approach to picture converting. Is it exist?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see these yellow artefacts is simply due to negative values for `byteL` overwriting bits from `byteH` containing the correct values for **red** and (part of) **green** channels. Let me explain.

Remember, if the highest bit in a byte is set to 1, the value is considered negative (-128 to -1 instead of 128 to 255), and by converting it to an `int` all the extra high-bits are set to 1 to conserve the same values (-128 to -1).

In your program, these extra bits set to 1 are in direct conflict with the value in `byteH` when applying the OR bit-operator `|`, overwriting (saturating) the red and (part of) green values you are trying to extract and display.

```
curPixel = (byteH << 8) | (byteL); // BUG: issue with negative byteL values
```

A solution is to apply an AND-mask to be sure to get rid of any unwanted bits before applying the OR bit-operator.

```
curPixel = byteL & 0xFF; // Convert byte to int to be within [0 , 255]
curPixel = (byteH << 8) | curPixel; // Apply OR bit-operator
```