# Extracting pixcel color values in byte[] from BItmap

Tags: android, android-bitmap

#### Background

I'm writing a simple application where app extracts the Pixel colors from the Bitmap in RGB_565 format and send it to bluetooth device via BLE

Im getting int[] of colors in `argb` format and i wanted in RGB_565 format 
so i extracted red, green , blue colors from `Color.red(-10267343)` where -10267343 is the color of the pixel i got from `getPixel(x,y)`

i got

```
red : 99
green : 85
blue : 99 //from the above color value -10267343
```

#### My question is how can i add these red, green, blue colors in two bytes

i need in this format `|R|R|R|R|R|G|G|G|G|G|G|B|B|B|B|B|`

So far i tried this method

```
byte[] colorToByte(int c){
  int r = (c >> 16) & 0xFF;
  int g = (c >> 8)  & 0xFF;
  int b =  c        & 0xFF;
  return new byte[]{(byte)((r&248)|g>>5),(byte)((g&28)<<3|b>>3)};
}
```

as suggested in this answer [How to correctly convert from rgb565 to rgb888](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842164/how-to-correctly-convert-from-rgb565-to-rgb888)

i tried this answer also but no luck [Java image conversion to RGB565](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319770/java-image-conversion-to-rgb565)

is there any way to solve this problem? any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static byte[] colorToByte(int c){
        int rgb = c;
        int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
        int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;

        int r_565 = red >> 3;
        int g_565 = green >> 2;
        int b_565 = blue >> 3;
        int rgb_565 = (r_565 << 11) | (g_565 << 5) | b_565;

        return new byte[]{(byte) ((rgb_565 >> 8) & 0xFF), (byte) (rgb_565 & 0xFF)};

        }
```